# How to Install and deploy a custom XML indexing connector for SharePoint Server 2016

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search, xml, registry

I have gone through the link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/xml_connector_for_sharepoint_2013/2012/10/01/create-a-custom-xml-indexing-connector-for-sharepoint-2013/

and trying to implement the same in SharePoint server 2016 and initially got  this error.

Item not crawled due to one of the following reasons: Preventive crawl rule; Specified content source hops/depth exceeded; URL has query string parameter; Required protocol handler not found; Preventive robots directive. ( This item was deleted because it was excluded by a crawl rule. )

Then I could able to narrow down to the point that Required protocol handler not found;

After checking in Registry editor (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE-->Microsoft-->Office Server-->16.0 -->Search--> ProtocolHandlers )

found that the same Protocol handler is not available and then I copied the same which was found in (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE-->Microsoft-->Office Server-->15.0 -->Search--> ProtocolHandlers ) and modified the value to OSearch16.ConnectorProtocolHandler.1 from earlier OSearch15.ConnectorProtocolHandler.1 which was found in 15.0 version and then restarted the search service.

Even then I full crawled. Got the below error.

Error while crawling LOB contents. ( Error caused by exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Parser.PackageFormatException The LobSystem with Name 'XmlDocumentSystem' and Id '2147483658' has a value in Field 'SystemUtilityType' that is invalid. Error was encountered at or just before Line: '25' and Position: '10'.; SearchID = B2567254-D024-49BB-A03E-D9978ADB55F6 )

Can anyone suggest how to Install and deploy a custom XML indexing connector for SharePoint Server 2016

Or even if you have answer to resolve my issues that would be great!

Comment: This is a very specific implementation with a lot of moving parts. Did you GAC the assembly on the crawl server? Did you create the taxonomy term set? Have you tried hooking up Visual Studio and debugging the code during the crawl?

Comment: Matthew, GAC ed the assembly using gacutil and then In the step (Create new content source for the XML content) when crawling I am getting that crawling error, did not try Visual studio because Visual studio is not installed on that server machine, if you could advise me on how to debug that would be great

Comment: I can't. I have never installed it. I will say that this is pretty advanced. You have to troubleshoot it one step at a time. Turn logging up to VerboseEx and watch the crawl component on your content source. Also, ensure that you have the correct permissions on the file share.